# How to create a dynamic table using form?

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular11

I have a dynamic table in the following conditions:

1. The user could add a new line;
2. In each line, always in the first column, there will be an input;
3. The user will be able to order or remove a certain column by the header;

The problem I'm having to create this table is that the data will be saved and requested from the backend, so I don't have a fixed amount of columns and rows.

With the above scenario, the table is in an infinite loop, and I can't use the input, whenever I type the value disappears.

**INPUT HTML**

```
<div>
  <app-input-search-filter
    (changeSymbolEvent)="changeSymbol($event)"
    [isLoading]="isLoading"
    name="assetSearchFilter"
    [$items]="$items"
    [control]="control"
    [isStyleInverse]="isStyleInverse"
    placeholder="Ativo"
  ></app-input-search-filter>
</div>
```

**INPUT TS**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime, filter, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SecurityAssetService } from 'src/app/OLD_CODE/core/services/security-asset.service';
import { IFilterItem } from '../../shared/forms/input-search-filter/input-search-filter.component';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-asset',
  templateUrl: './search-asset.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-asset.component.scss'],
})
export class SearchAssetComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() isStyleInverse?: boolean = false;
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  @Output() changeSymbolEvent = new EventEmitter();

  $items: Observable<IFilterItem[]>;
  isLoading: boolean = false;

  constructor(private securityAssetSvc: SecurityAssetService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.$items = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      tap(() => (this.isLoading = true)),
      switchMap((value) =>
        this._filter(value).then((response) => {
          if (response[0]?.symbol === '') {
            this.isLoading = false;
            return [];
          } else {
            this.isLoading = false;
            return response;
          }
        })
      )
    );
  }

  private async _filter(value: string): Promise<IFilterItem[]> {
    if (!value) return [];

    return await this.securityAssetSvc.getFilteredAssets(value);
  }

  changeSymbol(symbol: string) {
    this.changeSymbolEvent.emit(symbol);
  }
}
```

**TABLE HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngIf="hasBodyListData || hasHeadListData">ATIVO</th>
      <th *ngFor="let head of headList">{{ head }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody [ngClass]="{ 'table-quotation-body-hasdata': hasBodyListData }">
    <!-- DON'T HAVE DATA IN TABLE -->
    <tr *ngIf="!hasBodyListData; else hasData">
      <td [attr.colspan]="notHasDataColSpan">Sem dados a serem exibidos...</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- HAVE DATA IN TABLE -->
    <ng-template #hasData>
      <tr *ngFor="let bodyItemList of bodyList">
        <ng-template ngFor let-bodyItem let-i="index" [ngForOf]="bodyItemList">
           <!-- SEARCH FILTER -->
          <td *ngIf="i === 0">
            <app-search-asset (changeSymbolEvent)="changeSymbol($event)" [control]="getAssetFormControlByIndex(i)" [isStyleInverse]="isStyleInverse"></app-search-asset>
          </td>

          <td *ngIf="i !== 0">
            <!-- MASK -->
            <ng-container *ngIf="bodyItem.type; else notHasType">
              <span *ngIf="bodyItem.type.isCurrency">{{ bodyItem.value | currency:'BRL':'' }}</span>
              <span *ngIf="bodyItem.type.isNumber">{{ bodyItem.value }}</span>
              <span *ngIf="bodyItem.type.isPercentage">{{ bodyItem.value | percent }}</span>
              <span *ngIf="bodyItem.type.isDate">{{ bodyItem.value | date:'shortDate' }}</span>
              <span *ngIf="bodyItem.type.isHour">{{ bodyItem.value | date:'mediumTime' }}</span>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-template #notHasType>
              <span>{{ bodyItem.value }}</span>
            </ng-template>
          </td>
        </ng-template>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**TABLE TS**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { IFilterItem as IInputSearchFilter } from 'src/app/shared/forms/input-search-filter/input-search-filter.component';

export type Thead =
  | 'FECHAMENTO'
  | 'NEG'
  | 'DATA'
  | 'PR TEO'
  | 'PR MED'
  | 'VOL TEO'
  | 'AJU'
  | 'AJU ANT'
  | 'HR NEG'
  | 'QTD ULT'
  | 'QTD C'
  | 'QTD V'
  | 'QTD MC'
  | 'QTD MV'
  | 'QT COD'
  | 'LOTE'
  | 'CLASS'
  | 'HR PROG'
  | 'HR REPROG'
  | 'DT VENC'
  | 'ÚLTIMA'
  | '%'
  | 'HORA'
  | 'COMPRA'
  | 'VENDA'
  | 'MÁX'
  | 'MÍN'
  | 'ABERT.'
  | 'CLOSE'
  | 'VOL (Q)'
  | 'VOL ($)';

export interface ITbody {
  value?: number | string | Date;
  form?: {
    name: string;
    control: AbstractControl;
  }
  type?: {
    isCurrency?: boolean;
    isNumber?: boolean;
    isPercentage?: boolean;
    isDate?: boolean;
    isHour?: boolean;
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-quotation',
  templateUrl: './table-quotation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-quotation.component.scss'],
})
export class TableQuotationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() searchFilterItems: IInputSearchFilter[];
  @Input() headList: Thead[] = [];
  @Input() bodyList: ITbody[][] = [];

  get hasHeadListData(): boolean {
    return this.headList.length > 0;
  }

  get hasBodyListData(): boolean {
    return this.bodyList.length > 0;
  }

  get notHasDataColSpan(): string {
    return `${this.headList.length + 1}`;
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("AQUI")
  }

  getAssetFormControlByIndex(index: number): FormControl {
    return this.formControls[index];
  }

  getAssetFormControlNameByIndex(index: number): string {
    return `asset${index}`;
  }

  changeSymbol(symbol: string) {
    console.log("chegou1",symbol);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check if handsontable (https://handsontable.com/demo) can serve your purpose.